# Change tmux window list color

Tags: tmux, solarized

I want to change the color of window list selection highlight (yellow on the [screenshot](http://s21.postimg.org/dk353fyk7/2015_04_01_221012_990x555_scrot.png)), but can't find the proper parameter.

[image]

Anyone knows how to do it in `.tmux.conf`?

My [current configuration](http://xsnippet.org/360613/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the foreground and background colors of this window screen with these options:

```
setw -g mode-bg colour7
setw -g mode-fg black
```

Try some different values. What they look like depends on your Terminal, which you probably can configure, too.

Comment: Ah, that works :) Thank you for the answer!

Since I'm using `urxvt`, its colors are configured in `.Xdefaults` file. I have mine set for Solarized colors (with easy switch between light and dark mode): [.Xdefaults](https://github.com/zoresvit/dotfiles/blob/master/xorg/.Xdefaults) (in case someone will be intereseted).